# How to use mounted partition's data

Tags: 18.04, mount, xubuntu, live-usb

If I boot with the Live CD Ubuntu 18.04, and mount previously installed same Ubuntu, how can I use Firefox, for example? And save data after I log off so I can mount the next time again and keep on using it.

Comment: Depends on the kind of data, but generally, you'd have to take care of file permissions, and, in the case of Firefox, either migrate an existing profile, or add it to FF from the live cd. I doubt, it would be useful or practical though.

Comment: You can run Ubuntu from a DVD and keep it's casper-rw persistence partition on a different drive. Make a ext4 partition on a separate drive and label it casper-rw. When booting Ubuntu press Shift and then F6 then type <space>persistent. the session changes will be saved in the casper-rw partition. Boot the next session the same way to use the persistence or boot normally for a Live session.